# Highlight multi_match doesnt take last term

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search for multiple keywords, the last term is not highlighted in the result.

This is the index and mapping:

```
PUT objects
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my search:

```
// query
GET objects/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Goldenen Vlies",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "title._2gram",
        "title._3gram",
        "title._index_prefix"
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

The output I get is the following:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {...},
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 23,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 7.628418,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "objects",
        "_id" : "AWj1tIEBIysZ6sOt9vqw",
        "_score" : 7.628418,
        "highlight" : {
          "title" : [
            "Schwurkreuz des Ordens vom <em>Goldenen</em> Vlies" <-------
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, this would be the expected/desired output:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {...},
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 23,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 7.628418,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "objects",
        "_id" : "AWj1tIEBIysZ6sOt9vqw",
        "_score" : 7.628418,
        "highlight" : {
          "title" : [
            "Schwurkreuz des Ordens vom <em>Goldenen</em> <em<Vlies</em>" <-------
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It does work as expected when I add an extra empty space in the query like so: `"query": "Goldenen Vlies ",` but I want to know if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way with "best_fields":

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Goldenen Vlies",
      "type": "best_fields",
        "fields": [
        "title",
        "title._2gram",
        "title._3gram",
        "title._index_prefix"
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, but this does not seem to give me correct results Im after, for instance when I search for `Goldenen Vli` it doesnt take `Vli` into account at all.